# Использование генератора и массива

Tags: php, массивы, генераторы

Предыстория: я делаю некий обработчик, и на входных данных я получаю обычный массив, следующего формата:

```
$data = ['guid', 'inp', 'outx', 'dcfoaf'];
```

*(элементы этого массива - скажем так, некие ключи доступа)*

Итак, ближе к теме, у меня есть другие данные, которые я обрабатываю через цикл `foreach`, и, в процессе выполнения этого цикла, у меня есть переменная (к примеру `$xkey`), в которой случайно выбирается один из ключей массива `$data` с помощью функции `array_rand`.

Но я подумал, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы во время обработки моего цикла, с каждой итерацией элемент массива `$data` выводился по порядку? Например:

- Первая итерация цикла `foreach` (в переменной `$xkey` должно быть значение `guid`)
- Вторая итерация цикла `foreach` (в переменной `$xkey` должно быть значение `inp`)

И тому подобное

***Но***, в чем сложность самого вопроса решения этой задачи, нужно это сделать так, чтобы (когда элементы массива `$data` заканчиваются) они вызывались в очередной раз сначала. На пятой итерации в переменной `$xkey` должно быть значение `guid`, а на шестой `inp`.

Спустя время, я нашел материал про [генераторы в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php), в котором я увидел оператор `yield`, там было написано следующее:

> Вся суть генератора заключается в ключевом слове yield. В самом простом варианте оператор "yield" можно рассматривать как оператор "return", за исключением того, что вместо прекращения работы функции, "yield" только приостанавливает ее выполнение и возвращает текущее значение, и при следующем вызове функции она возобновит выполнения с места, на котором прервалась.

Я так и не разобрался как можно реализовать решение задачи с помощью этого, прошу помочь с реализацией (на простых примерах тоже приветствуется), и возможна ли она вообще? Жду любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: эм. `$xkey = $data[ $i % 5]` , или поясните про сложность?

Comment: @teran, вот [`тут`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21cec08d70026dca52b3629665a0e51e60adea2f) написал задачу иначе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно воспользоваться штатным `InfiniteIterator`, доступным уже очень давно, с PHP 5.1.0

```
$data = ['guid', 'inp', 'outx', 'dcfoaf'];
// вот и весь фокус:
$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($data));

$i = 0;
foreach ($infinite as $xkey) {
    echo '$xkey = '.$xkey.PHP_EOL;
    if (++$i > 30) break; // чтобы хоть когда-нибудь прерваться
}
```

---

Можно и через генератором воспользоваться:

```
$data = ['guid', 'inp', 'outx', 'dcfoaf'];
$infinite = function($input) {
    while (true) {
        yield from $input;
    }
};

$i = 0;
foreach ($infinite($data) as $xkey) {
    echo '$xkey = '.$xkey.PHP_EOL;
    if (++$i > 30) break;
}
```

---

А в принципе и PHP4 достаточно с указателем на элемент массива:

```
$data = ['guid', 'inp', 'outx', 'dcfoaf'];

$i = 0;
$xkey = current($data); // получаем первый элемент
while (true) {
    echo '$xkey = '.$xkey.PHP_EOL;
    if (++$i > 30) break;

    $xkey = next($data);
    if ($xkey === false) {
        // следующего нет, берём вновь начало
        $xkey = reset($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

как еще один вариант решения без итераторов, уже упомянутый мною в комментарии, но обернутый в желаемую форму последовательного вызова функций:

```
$data = ['guid', 'inp', 'outx', 'dcfoaf'];

function demark(){
    static $i = 0;

    global $data;

    return $data[ $i++ % count($data)];
}

echo demark();
echo demark();
echo demark();
echo demark();
echo demark();
echo demark();
echo demark();
```

Comment: Как разделить галочку принятого ответ надвое? :D

Comment: спасибо большое, хороший вариант